# Difference between Quartz Thread Pool and Task Executor

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm working in Spring-quartz batch. I'm trying to implement Multi-threading for the Batch application.

I come across 2 possible way of multi threading,

1. Use Quartz Thread pool
2. Use Task Executors.

I used Quartz thread pool and it is working fine but was wondering what the advantage i will get if i also implement task Executor.

I'm doing all this as xml configuration.

Please suggest me which should be used and what is the benefit of one over the other.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would choose task executors if all you need is to keep N workers picking pieces of work from the common queue. The advantage is that you do not need any external libraries for this. Quartz thread pool was created before Java 5 - that is why it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Executor is good enough for running concurrent tasks within a JVM. But if you want to distribute tasks across multiple JVMs in a clustered environment, then you should explore Quartz using the JDBC Store. 
Quartz is more of a scheduling framework where you can setup jobs to run on a periodic basis. But I have also used it heavily for concurrent programming.